# Flask - prevent function from reloading?

Tags: python-3.x, flask

I am not sure how to explain the issue, but I am trying to get flask to load my `main()` function once, and then stay "within" that function as the user clicks buttons.

I have a list of image names (e.g. `20190101.jpg`, `20190111.jpg`, `20190323.jpg`) that are baiscally in `YYYYMMDD.jpg` format.

When I first load my site, I want it to show all images.  However, I have also added a Calendar Picker that allows the user to select a date, and on the date selection, my `routes.py` looks for images in that range only, and returns those for view.

I can do this part, no problem.  The issue is when the users click the "next photo"/"previous photo"/"random" button, or select an image from my table list.  When they do that, the default photo list loads, instead of the filtered one.

As I have it, I understand that's because `main()` is getting called on the button click, and I have `_images = image_urls` at the very top, so it is effectively resetting the list.

How can I write my function(s) to load `_images = image_urls` ONCE, and then keep that list and update only as the user tells it to?

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>{{ title }}</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href= "{{ url_for('static',filename='styles/index.css') }}">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='favicon.ico') }}">
</head>
<body>
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block content %}
    <h3>Index: {{ photo_index }}</h3>
    <h3>Filename: {{ image }}</h3>
    {% include "/HTML Snippets/calendar.html" %}
    <div class='image-container' id='image'>
        {% include "/HTML Snippets/favorite_button.html" %}
        <img src="{{ url_for('images.static', filename=image) }} " id="the-photo">
    </div>
    <div class='button-container' id='buttons'>
        <form action="" method="post">
            <input type="hidden" name="prev-next-buttons">
            <input type="submit" value="Prev photo" name='prev-photo'>
            <input type="submit" value="Next photo" name='next-photo'>
            <input type="submit" value="Random photo" name='random-photo'>
            <br/>
            <button type='button' id='rotate-button' onclick="rotateMeCounterClockwise('#the-photo')">Rotate Photo CounterClockwise</button>
            <button type='button' id='rotate-button' onclick="rotateMeClockwise('#the-photo')">Rotate Photo Clockwise</button>
        </form>
        <h3>Choose image from list:</h3>
        <form method="post">
            <input type="hidden" name="photo-select">
            <select name="select-image" onfocus='this.size=5;' onblur='this.size=1' onchange="this.size=1;  this.blur(); this.form.submit()">
                {% for eimage in image_list %}
                    <option 
                    {% if eimage == image %} 
                        selected 
                    {% endif %}
                    value = {{ eimage }}
                    >
                        {{eimage}}
                    </option>
                {% endfor %}
            </select>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class='table-container'>
        <table id='image-list' name='select-from-table'>
            {% for image_row in image_list | batch(3) %}
            <tr>
                {% for image in image_row %}
                <td><a href="{{ url_for('main', chosen_image=image) }}"> {{ image }} </a></td>
                {% endfor %}
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
        </table>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

calendar.html

```
{% block topscripts %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href= "{{ url_for('static',filename='styles/calendar.css') }}">
    <script>
        $(function() {
            $("#datepicker").datepicker();
        });
    </script>    
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<form method="post">
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"  name='go-to-date'></p>
    <input type="hidden" name="calendar-form">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
{% endblock %}

{% block endscripts %}

{% endblock %}
```

routes.py

```
[imports and misc]
images = os.listdir(IMAGE_FOLDER)


def create_urls(files):
    image_urls = []
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith(".jpg"):
            image_urls.append(file)
    return image_urls


image_urls = create_urls(images)
image_urls.append('favicon.ico')
# Subtract 2 below, so you don't include the
# favicon.ico
num_images = len(image_urls) - 2


class Photo_Index():
    def __init__(self, index=0):
        self.index = index

    def increase_number(self):
        if self.index == num_images:
            self.index = 0
        else:
            self.index = self.index + 1
        return self.index

    def decrease_number(self):
        if self.index == 0:
            self.index = num_images
        else:
            self.index = self.index - 1
        return self.index

    def random_number(self):
        self.index = random.randint(0, num_images)
        return self.index

    def set_number(self, number):
        self.index = number
        return self.index

...

def day_month_year(filename):
    """
    Takes a string `20190212` and pulls out Year, Month, Date
    """
    year = filename[:4]
    month = filename[4:6]
    day = filename[6:8]
    return str(year + "-" + month + "-" + day)


def get_files_on(specific_date):
    _files = []
    print("\nLooking for files on:", specific_date, "\n")
    for file in image_urls:
        # print(file, day_month_year(file))
        if day_month_year(file) == specific_date:
            _files.append(file)
    return _files


photo_index_obj = Photo_Index()
fav_photo_index = Photo_Index()


def update_index(rqst, indx_obj):
    if 'prev-photo' in rqst.form:
        indx_obj.decrease_number()
    elif 'next-photo' in rqst.form:
        indx_obj.increase_number()
    elif 'random-photo' in rqst.form:
        indx_obj.random_number()
    return indx_obj


@app.route("/", methods=["GET", "POST"])
@app.route("/<chosen_image>", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def main(chosen_image=None):
    _images = image_urls
    if request.method == "POST":
        if 'go-to-date' in request.form:
            spec_date = request.form['go-to-date']
            spec_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(spec_date, "%m/%d/%Y").strftime("%Y-%m-%d") # noqa
            _images = get_files_on(spec_date)
        elif 'prev-next-buttons' in request.form:
            update_index(request, photo_index_obj)
        elif 'photo-select' in request.form:
            img = request.form.get("select-image")
            photo_index_obj.set_number(_images.index(str(img)))
        elif 'favorite-photo' in request.form:
            add_to_favorites(_images[photo_index_obj.index])
        elif 'un-favorite-photo' in request.form:
            remove_from_favorites(_images[photo_index_obj.index])
    if request.method == "GET":
        if chosen_image is not None:
            photo_index_obj.set_number(_images.index(chosen_image))
    favorite = is_favorite(_images[photo_index_obj.index])
    return render_template('index.html',
                           title="Local Image Viewer",
                           photo_index=photo_index_obj.index,
                           image=_images[photo_index_obj.index],
                           image_list=_images,
                           favorite=favorite)
```

(I tried to keep routes.py to show just the minimum required, but if you want to see any functions specifically, please let me know).

[Here's an example of what I mean](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qNwHV.gif) - on load, it shows all images.  I can then choose a date, and the routes.py updates the `_images` list to include just those on that date (yay!). **But** when I click "next picture", instead of going to the next picture in the *new* `_images`, it reloads the images from `image_urls`. I understand that's because the first line in `main()` is `_images = image_urls`. (I'm learning Flask so I also understand my function is a little kludgy).

My question is how do I properly set these at first, but then *after* main is called the first time, use `_images` as set in the code?

Answer (score 2):

What you ask for is quite similar to URL filters and pagination. Widespread practice (you can see it on most php-based blogs/e-shops/etc.) is when you click on a date, you apply a date filter, so your front-end makes a request like `GET localhost?date=1.1.2019` and your flask app should extract that date and return images based on that filter. By default, first image of that list should be returned and when you click a next photo button, you make a request like `GET localhost?date=1.1.2019&offset=2`. Offset means that you need a second image (or page) from the all filtered results.

Comment: So I'm making headway with this. If I pass the date to the URL, I can get the filters working.  Where it gets tricky is when/how to reset the index to use the updated URLs.  Is `offset` a "built in" method, or is that something I'll have to pass too? As you can see, right now I'm using a variable to keep track of the indexing.

Comment: The core thing is to _not track_ index in flask and do it on the front-end, it's called a stateless backend/service. Offset, in this particular case (because in SQL DBs it's an operator), is just a variable, which indicates what image is "current" and should be shown in center. It's not front-end commands to flask: "show me next image", but front-end commands: "ok, current date is X, and current image offset=Y, a link for next image should be localhost?date=X&offset=Y+1".

Comment: Thanks for that - that's where I am having trouble visualizing how I'd do that part, "current image is X, next should be Y"...